# Computing the limit of $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

Hello I was wondering where I could start with computing this limit $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{n^2}{2^n}$ . This is a proof based intro analysis class and recently we were taught epsilon neighborhoods but in this situation solving for $n$ doesn't seem like it will work. Any ideas of other ways to go about this ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Do you want $\sum_{n=3}^\infty n^2/2^n$? or $\sum_{n=3}^\infty n^2/2^n$?

Comment: i think you have missed a sigma

Comment: yes i forgot the sigma sorry ill figure out how to add that... dont usually use latex

Comment: Hint: $\sum n(n+1)x^{n-1}$ is an $f''(x)$.

Comment: Are you trying to find the limit or show that it exists? Two very different questions.

Comment: the question states to compute the limit so i think i need to actually find it

Comment: Wolfram alpha can do it, if you want to check your answer.  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%3D3+to+infinity+n%5E2%2F2%5En

Answer (score 10):

We know that for $|x|<1$

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$

Differentiating wrt $x$ and multiplying by $x$

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} = x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1}$

By doing it another time, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2x^n = \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}$

I let you finish...